# Apply function on method parameter

Tags: scala, methods, implicit

I need to update a field in a method which is called from many places. I want all values which are given to the field to be uppercase. But I don't want to transform it inside the methods where it's required. And don't want to create another value. I'm asking if I can use a type of implicits to transform the value?

```
def parent(itemType: String) =
   getValue(itemType.toUperCase)
```

or

```
def parent(itemType: String) = 
   getValue(itemType)

getValue(itemType: String) = {
  val formattedValue = itemType.toUperCase
}
```

I want to avoid both approaches, and ask for something like:

```
getValue(itemType: String = itemType.toUperCase) = { 
   // use itemType as upercase value
}
```

Comment: What is a "field in a method"?

Comment: Both your approaches are ok. Pick one. If you need to call both the upper-casing and original method, make a wrapper. If not `def foo(_i: String) = {val i = _i.toUpperCase; ...}

Comment: apply a function on a field from method definition: `def getValue(itemType: String // here, I want to format the itemType to UperCase directly if it is possible)`

Comment: Using mutable values and calling a method "get" is not idiomatic Scala. Use an immutable class and convert the value to upper case in the constructor (`apply` method in companion object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing would be to reify the uppercaseness in the type system.

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Refined {
  class UppercaseString private[Refined](override val toString: String) extends AnyVal

  implicit def stringToUpper(s: String): UppercaseString = new UppercaseString(s.toUpperCase)

  implicit def upperToString(ucs: UppercaseString): String = ucs.toString
}
```

Then you can express that a string must be uppercase (and transparently make a regular string uppercase) with

```scala
import Refined._

def getValue(itemType: UppercaseString) = ???
```

The presence of the implicit conversion to `UppercaseString` means that, as long as `Refined.stringToUpper` has been imported, we can call `getValue` with arbitrary strings.

Because `UppercaseString` extends `AnyVal`, in many cases it will have no overhead beyond the uppercased string.  Since it's a type, calling code can save it as an `UppercaseString` and save calls to `toUpperCase`.

Note that `implicit class` doesn't work here as we want to perform an operation in the process of "construction"; the constructor of `UppercaseString` is `private` to `Refined` so that we can ensure that all creation goes through `toUpperCase`.